# Unable to connect to source game servers requiring steam servers

Tags: steam, technical-issues

I've tried to connect to servers for games like Garry's Mod, Dota 2, CS:GO and none of them have worked I get a error message like this: [image]

I've tried port forwarding, virus scanning, disabling firewall, reinstalling ClientRegistry.blob and AppUpdateStats.blob, DMZ mode, allowing steam through firewall, verifying game cache and none of it has worked.
The weird thing about it is that only a handful of servers work but not all of them.

Comment: What kind of network is this?  If you are doing it at a school or something it might be blocked.

Comment: I'm doing it on my home connection, leeching off my neighbors (my uncle) he's trying to help me get this sorted. Not sure if this is a computer problem though, I've been trying to look into my lan card which is a Realtek PcIe GBE Family Controller, I can't rollback the driver.

Comment: For clarification: This happens ONLY to Valve games (try TF2)?  This happens on all servers you try connecting to?  Not to get too personal but where are you located (country)?  Are you trying to connect to foreign servers?  Have you connected to any of these servers before?

Comment: I've been having issues with all kinds of games Trine 2, Team Fortress 2, etc mostly games with source servers. This happens to a majority of servers I try to connect to, only a handful of servers work for me. I am located in the U.S, New Mexico. And no, not trying to connect to foreign servers, I connect to the ones located in the U.S.

Comment: Are you using peer block? If so, try disabling it.

Comment: By default, Valve games use UDP port 27015 for the server's query port.  The actual connection for the game uses a different port (UDP 27005 by default), though.

Comment: Are there any port blocks on the router of your neighbor-uncle? Most routers have an open config by default, but some lock down most ports except for the common mail/http/etc ports. I assume this is on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling/enabling Steam Beta participation and if that fails, try deleting appcache and even  your Steam folder if you have to.